# How to read parameters of layers of .tflite model in python

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I was trying to read tflite model and pull all the parameters of the layers out.

My steps:

1. I generated flatbuffers model representation by running (please build flatc before):

`flatc -python tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/schema/schema.fbs`

Result is `tflite/` folder that contains layer description files (`*.py`) and some utilitarian files.

2. I successfully loaded model:

in case of import Error: set PYTHONPATH to point to the folder where tflite/ is

```
from tflite.Model import Model
def read_tflite_model(file):
    buf = open(file, "rb").read()
    buf = bytearray(buf)
    model = Model.GetRootAsModel(buf, 0)
    return model
```

3. I partly pulled model and node parameters out and stacked in iterating over nodes:

Model part:

```
def print_model_info(model):
        version = model.Version()
        print("Model version:", version)
        description = model.Description().decode('utf-8')
        print("Description:", description)
        subgraph_len = model.SubgraphsLength()
        print("Subgraph length:", subgraph_len)
```

Nodes part:

```
def print_nodes_info(model):
    # what does this 0 mean? should it always be zero?
    subgraph = model.Subgraphs(0)
    operators_len = subgraph.OperatorsLength()
    print('Operators length:', operators_len)

    from collections import deque
    nodes = deque(subgraph.InputsAsNumpy())

    STEP_N = 0
    MAX_STEPS = operators_len
    print("Nodes info:")
    while len(nodes) != 0 and STEP_N <= MAX_STEPS:
        print("MAX_STEPS={} STEP_N={}".format(MAX_STEPS, STEP_N))
        print("-" * 60)

        node_id = nodes.pop()
        print("Node id:", node_id)

        tensor = subgraph.Tensors(node_id)
        print("Node name:", tensor.Name().decode('utf-8'))
        print("Node shape:", tensor.ShapeAsNumpy())

        # which type is it? what does it mean?
        type_of_tensor = tensor.Type()
        print("Tensor type:", type_of_tensor)

        quantization = tensor.Quantization()
        min = quantization.MinAsNumpy()
        max = quantization.MaxAsNumpy()
        scale = quantization.ScaleAsNumpy()
        zero_point = quantization.ZeroPointAsNumpy()
        print("Quantization: ({}, {}), s={}, z={}".format(min, max, scale, zero_point))

        # I do not understand it again. what is j, that I set to 0 here?
        operator = subgraph.Operators(0)
        for i in operator.OutputsAsNumpy():
            nodes.appendleft(i)

        STEP_N += 1

    print("-"*60)
```

Please point me to documentation or some example of using this API.

My problems are:

1. I can not get documentation on this API
2. Iterating over Tensor objects seems not possible for me, as it doesn't have Inputs and Outputs methods.  + `subgraph.Operators(j=0)` I do not understand what j means in here. Because of that my cycle goes through two nodes: input (once) and the next one over and over again.
3. Iterating over Operator objects is surely possible:

Here we iterate over them all but I can not get how to map Operator and Tensor.

```
def print_in_out_info_of_all_operators(model):
    # what does this 0 mean? should it always be zero?
    subgraph = model.Subgraphs(0)
    for i in range(subgraph.OperatorsLength()):
        operator = subgraph.Operators(i)
        print('Outputs', operator.OutputsAsNumpy())
        print('Inputs', operator.InputsAsNumpy())
```

3. I do not understand how to pull parameters out Operator object. BuiltinOptions method gives me Table object, that I do not know what to map at.
4. `subgraph = model.Subgraphs(0)` 
   What does this 0 mean? should it always be zero? obviously no, but what is it? Id of the subgraph? If so - I'm happy. If no, please try to explain it.